# Find $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+1)(k-1)!}.$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How can I evaluate the following series.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+1)(k-1)!}.$$

Comment: Any ideas yourself? What tools do you know?

Comment: @angela93 Multiply numerator and denomenator by k.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+1)(k-1)!} 
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k+1}{(k+1)!} - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+1)!}$$

I think the following is easy to solve

Comment: I think the 2nd on RHS is $ e-2$. What about the first one

Comment: @user41736 $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k+1}{(k+1)!} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!} = e - 1$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(k+1)(k-1)!} 
= 1 - \frac{1}{(n+1)!}.$$

So

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+1)(k-1)!} 
= 1. $$